# Is it necessary to lock a variable when reading it in different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Please tell me if it is necessary to block data in a multithreaded program if :

1. I want to read the same variable in two threads, but not change it.
2. I want to ALWAYS read in the first stream, and change in the second.
   Thank you very much!

Comment: Variable of which type? Anyway, it's hard to answer, since "(b)locking a variable/data" is kind of non-standard terminology. Do you mean to synchronize access to it? Or, to synchronize it with an explicit lock (mutex,...)?

Comment: 1. **No**, not necessary. 2. **Yes**, necessary.

Comment: bool in this case

Comment: @Artem.rtv With `bool`, you can use `std::atomic<bool>` in the second case. Then, no additional lock is required.